# jquery .animate is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/2mRMr/3/

this code is not working :

```
setInterval(function () {
        box.animate({
            left: function (i, v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); },
            top: function (i, v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
        });

    }, 20);
```

while this do :

```
setInterval(function () {
        box.css({
            left: function (i, v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); },
            top: function (i, v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
        });

    }, 20);
```

any help please  ?

Comment: It doesn't work that way! You can't replace css with animate inside an interval where you call a function on every iteration to return the css values etc. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: please see my jsfiddle Box is the little red rectangle

Comment: but i want to do an animation bcs as u can see the way the rectangle move when using cursor is to slow and boring for eyes to see so i thought i can use an animation to give it more life

Comment: what is v in function (i, v) ?

Comment: Don't we need jquery-ui for using `animate`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as adeneo said - using `setInterval` you create own animation so you don't need jQuery `animate()` inside. `animate()` probably also use `setInterval` to make animation. You modify `left` and `top` using `setInterval` and `newv()` and animate() try to modify `left` and `top` using own `setInterval` at the same time.

btw: in [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can use `step()` to modify value in every step (without own `setInterval`) but I never used it.

Comment: um fine i get the idea but i was wondering if their is some work around code that i should use to change the way the box movement and make it more smoother ?

Comment: Using `setInterval` in own function you have better control and your animation can interact with keyboard. With `animate()` you couldn't do this. In some situation you can't do this smoother - you can't move half pixel ;)

Comment: If you are going to create game see [HTML5 Game Engines](http://html5gameengine.com)

Comment: hmmm ok than i guess it's either using html 5 canvas or i would be stuck in this

Comment: They use canvas because it probably have hardware acceleration. See also [Paper.js vs. Processing.js vs. Raphael](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/22/web-drawing-throwdown-paper-processing-raphael)